# Dynamic UIView size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, autolayout

The problem that I have is that somehow the UIView gets an undesirable padding. It seems that the UIView frame resizes itself based on the UIImage height.

[These are my constraints on the UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUAdk.jpg)

[Illustrative GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hTI6.jpg)

Cell Configuration:

```
// Configure the cell...
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.testView.frame.width, height: cell.testView.frame.height))

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "eiffel.JPG")
    imageView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.center = cell.testView.center
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    cell.testView.addSubview(imageView)

    let bottomMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.testView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let topMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.testView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let trailingMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.testView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let leadingMarginConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.testView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    //let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: .None, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: imageView.superview!.frame.width)

    let constraints = [bottomMarginConstraint, topMarginConstraint, leadingMarginConstraint, trailingMarginConstraint]

    cell.testView.addConstraints(constraints)
```

The UIView is the one with the light green background and the Cell the one with the pink background.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to resize the image based on it's width and then modify the height constraint based on the recalculated height.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the margin that are added by default while using auto layout.
Uncheck it from the storyboard.

- Uncheck `"Constrain to margin"`

[image: Method 1]

**Or**

- Uncheck `"Relative To Margin"`

[image: Method 2]

- Try to remove programatically

`imageView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,0);`

See More:
[iOS8 Auto layout programatically pin to relative layout margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157077/ios8-auto-layout-programatically-pin-to-relative-layout-margin)

[Apple Doc Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me! I uploaded my project here -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikmvtgk6gs12epl/UIImageViewRatioFullSizeTest.zip?dl=0 please help! I reeeeeally don't know what to do now :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can draw the `UIImageView` in xib too. The size of `UIImageView` will be changed too when the image changed in `Auto layout`. You just need to confirm the position of `UIImageView`.

When tableView need to know the height of this cell, return `cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).size.height + 1` to calculate the height of Cell's contentView and `1.f` of seperator line