# How can I get the size of a view's margin?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a UIViewController, and I want to update another view within the controller so that the leading space is a certain distance from the left margin.

My question is how do I get the size of the margin or how do I position something with respect to the margin?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26305124/4905076) I might give an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The view's left margin size is `view.layoutMargins.left`.

You can get a layout anchor for the left margin as `view.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor`. Example:

```
subview.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.layoutMargins.leftAnchor).active = true
```

Note though that if you want your interface to flip correctly in a right-to-left locale, you should use `leadingAnchor`:

```
subview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.layoutMargins.leadingAnchor).active = true
```

If you want to create a layout constraint using the old `NSLayoutConstraint.
init(item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:)`
 constructor, the attributes are named `.LeftMargin` and `.LeadingMargin`.